# Atom: Cannot load the system dictionary for en_IN. Checked the following paths for dictionary files:

Tags: atom-editor, ubuntu-18.04

When I open Atom editor it shows the following error message. How to resolve the same?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have resolved this problem using language update in editor following way:

1) **Atom → Edit → Preferences → Packages**

2) `search for "spell check" and deselect Use Locales button and mention en-US (editor support language) in custom bar.`

3) After restart the editor.

[image]

Comment: It is written there `If unchecked, then the locales below will **NOT** be used for spell-checking...`, then why do you uncheck `Use Locales` and provide a locale? I think it works in your system just because you might be using windows or OSX and have `Use System` checked with correct language installed.

Answer (score 5):

You might be missing the system dictionaries.

Go to settings with `ctrl-,` and look in `Packages` for the package `spell-check`. Enter its settings.

1. Make sure `Use Locales` is selected (default, I believe).
2. Write the necessary locales in the `Locales` box, for example `en_US, pt_PT` would work for both American English and European Portuguese. This is useful for those who write in multiple languages.
3. Install the necessary dictionaries on your system. In this case that would be:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install hunspell-pt-pt hunspell-en-us`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Windows. The problem was not by Atom. The system was missing the right language. I added the language and reopened Atom and the error didn't come up anymore.