# Atom: The package spell-check cannot load the checker for es-CL

Tags: windows, atom-editor

When I open Atom editor in Windows 10, it shows the following warning message:

[image]

I've installed the language pack for Spanish from Chile (es-CL), and tried suggestions from the post [Atom: Cannot load the system dictionary for en_IN. Checked the following paths for dictionary files:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963175/atom-cannot-load-the-system-dictionary-for-en-in-checked-the-following-paths-f). I'm trying to use two languages for spell checking with `spell-check` (en-US, es-CL), which was working some time ago. Now it only works for en-US. How can both dictionaries be used for spell checking?

Comment: By the way, the use of two languages in `spell-check` (`en-US, es-CL`) works fine in Ubuntu 20.04